# How to switch ddrescue from `/dev/sdq1` to `/dev/sdq` if I've already backed up data from `/dev/sdq1`?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, data-recovery, ddrescue

I started to recover my `/dev/sdq1` when I was not familiar with HDD recovery. Well, I was careful enough and recover 85% in about 500 runs.

Afterwards, I've found out that I need `/dev/sdq` (without 1) contents actually to convert them after to `.vhd` with `VBoxManage convertdd z:\fixed.vdi d:\disc.vhd --format VHD` and after I can attach and read that `.vhd` in Windows, because `VBoxManage` does not support *partition* conversion and requires *full harddrive* raw data as an input. That means I should have started ddrescue with `/dev/sdq` and not `/dev/sdq1`.

I've found out that contents of `/dev/sdq1` start at 32256 byte of `/dev/sdq` with fdisk. I `dd`ed these bytes at the beginning to separate file `begin.raw` and now running `cat ./rescue/begin.raw ./rescue/fixed.vdi > ./sdq.raw` to prepend them to recovered data from `/dev/sdq1`.

Is there an easier way to continue runs of `ddrescue` to that new `./sdq.raw` with old rescuelog? I'm not sure that `--output-position` will fit here. (and how does it work exactly? -- This is not clear from docs how `output-position` will influence on rescuelog interpretation).
I don't want to copy 500GB each time I want to get my `./sdq.raw`.

Below is my script I use to recover data. Sometimes I had to detach HDD physically because my usb hub does not support complete power off on its ports.

```
#!/bin/bash
function run {
    ddrescue -T 5s --max-error-rate=10MB --skip-size=512KiB,10MiB \
        --direct -vv -P /dev/sdq1 ./fixed.vdi ./rescue.log
}

while true; do
    run &
    JOBPID=$!
    while true; do
        dmesg | tail -1 | grep 'reset high-speed USB device number' > /dev/null
        CODE=$?
        if [ $CODE -eq 0 ]; then
            break
        fi
        kill -0 "$JOBPID" > /dev/null
        CODE=$?
        if [ $CODE -ne 0 ]; then
            break
        fi
        sleep 3
    done
    ./uhubctl -i -a 2 -p 1 -l 1
    wait $JOBPID
    echo "MSG: waiting for re-attach"
    until dmesg | tail -1 | grep 'Attached SCSI disk'; do sleep 1; done
    sleep 5
done
```

Thanks!

P. S. I have Logitech USB 2.0 hub but it does not support full poweroff on ports either with `uhubctl`. Maybe there's other tool that can work with it?

Comment: If USB ports refuse to power off, try using -r N option for uhubctl (I am uhubctl author). Use higher N to make sure it is really off for good.

Comment: Do you need to convert the file repeatedly during the rescue operation? What is wrong with running `ddrescue` as far as it gets, then prepending `begin.raw` once and for all, then converting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether `--output-position` is the right `ddrescue` option or not, **I present the general Linux way to concatenate two files without writing the result to disk.**

The tool is `dmsetup`. It is in the `dmsetup` package in my Kubuntu, the same in Debian.

We have `begin.raw` of the size `32256 B` and `fixed.vdi` corresponding to the partition of the size `<X>` (about `500 GB`, the exact value unknown to me). We need to express the sizes in `512 B` unit; the results are `63` and `<Y>` respectively. In the code below you have to replace `<Y>` with the computed value, so don't copy-paste it mindlessly.

```
# Creating loop devices and storing their names.
BEGIN_LOOP=$(sudo losetup -f --show begin.raw)
FIXED_LOOP=$(sudo losetup -f --show fixed.vdi)

# Creating a map to feed to `dmsetup` later.
# !!! REPLACE <Y> WITH THE PROPER VALUE !!!
echo "0 63 linear $BEGIN_LOOP 0" > whole.map
echo "63 <Y> linear $FIXED_LOOP 0" >> whole.map

# Creating a concatenated "file".
sudo dmsetup create whole.raw < whole.map
ln -s /dev/mapper/whole.raw
```

You can now use `whole.raw` as an image of the entire disk while `ddrescue` may still work with `fixed.vdi`. Every I/O operation on `whole.raw` will be mapped to `begin.raw` and `fixed.vdi`.

Note that this mapping is not persistent. After a reboot you need to repeat the whole procedure except `ln -s`.

To clean this setup without rebooting, invoke:

```
rm whole.raw                    # removes the symlink
sudo dmsetup remove whole.raw   # removes /dev/mapper/whole.raw
sudo losetup -d $FIXED_LOOP     # removes /dev/loop1 (or so)
sudo losetup -d $BEGIN_LOOP     # removes /dev/loop0 (or so)
```

If you lose the variables somehow (e.g. by closing the terminal emulator) then examine the output of `losetup -a` and do `sudo losetup -d /dev/loopX` accordingly.