# How to mount a partition by specifying block range instead of partition on Linux?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount

Dear Linux super users,

I'd like to mount a filesystem that whose *range* I would like to ommit from the *partition table* in order to *hide* it from anyone looking for data on my disk.

This capability together with volatile/non-fstab mounts and dm-crypt plain would make my data very secure from people who are interested in my data or the possibility of data being there at all.

Is this possible with `mount(8)`?

Comment: You want `losetup` and particularly its `--offset` and `--sizelimit` switches. Once you have a loopback device configured, you should be able to mount it normally.

Comment: That may fool someone not looking very closely, but anyone using `binwalk` or scanning for file system signatures in some other way would find it easily, encrypted or not. Security by obscurity can buy you time, but it doesn't make it safer.

Comment: @dirkt I disagree about `binwalk` and signatures. *Contrary to LUKS, dm-crypt plain mode does not require a header on the encrypted device [...] encrypted disk that will be indistinguishable from a disk filled with random data, which could allow deniable encryption.* ([Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Plain_dm-crypt)).

Comment: @dirkt Security-through-obscurity can only buy you time, but that does not mean it is not part of a valid security system. Knowing its purposes and using it appropriately can increase general system security and it should not be downplayed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible with non-encrypted filesystem. E.g if your partition starts at the sector `34607104` and the sector size is `512`, you go with:

```
mount -o offset=$((512*34607104)) /dev/sdX /mnt/foo/
```

The partition table entry may or may not exist, it doesn't matter. `mount` will examine the filesystem and do its job (you can help with `-t` switch).

---

I don't know much about *dm-crypt plain* but it appears you should decrypt the device (partition) first, then mount. Michael Kjörling's comment is useful:

> You want `losetup` and particularly its `--offset` and `--sizelimit` switches. Once you have a loopback device configured, you should be able to mount it normally.

I would change the last words to "decrypt it normally" to fit your needs.

---

There is also `dmsetup` tool. It allows you to create a mapped device from chunks of various files/devices. E.g. you can hide your encrypted "partition" in several gaps between normal partitions inside one or more HDDs. Read [my answer to another question](https://superuser.com/a/1167639/432690) and study `man dmsetup`. Make your `/dev/mapper/barbaz` a franken-partition and have fun with plain encryption on it.

Hint: in the said answer I use `losetup` to create devices from files because `dmsetup` doesn't work with regular files. You will work with already existing devices. Use their `/dev/something` paths when building the map for `dmsetup` – no need for `losetup` in this case.

Comment: 1. Good tip about dmsetup! 2. I knew about losetup, but didn't know it can do devices too! So thanks @Michael too!