# Is there any way to block some partition unaffected

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, backup, operating-systems

I am working on some application where i need save some system state configuration files related to my application. So i want to save(Backup) it some where in the hard disk partition(as hidden or recovery partition) Whenever system crashes i can restore it. When System Crashes is it possible not to touch that partition while re-installing linux suse(or any other OS) and the files are still be available when the system is ready. When system Crashes or system re-install or OS change or some disaster happens the partition should not be affected.

Comment: in theory, yes.  technique might vary based on whether using MBR or GPT.  might be as easy as assigning the partition a partition id/type that doesn't match a known file type; you might even be able to manually mount it despite the wrong partition id/type, but lots of software may be less inclined to automatically muck with a partition of an unfamiliar type.

Comment: sir TOOGAM can you give more information i am unable to understand. As i am new please tell me in detail. thank you

Comment: Hiding something this way is what a virus would do. Your program should do [the least surprising thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). What if 20 other applications tried to do this your way? Why should yours be special? Put the config files in standard places (`/etc/`, `~/.*`) because users will expect them to be there. What if someone *wanted* to do a clean install? **Don't treat Linux users (and admins!) like children,** they should know how to save configs or purge them if they want to. Also: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Files will be saved in the natural place where it has to be. But my question is to backup them without any help from internet or other external storage devices.

Comment: OK, I get it. There are well known tools (like `rsync`) that can do backup to a separate well-defined partition (or wherever) with admin's support. Encourage admins to do so instead of reinventing the wheel and implementing application-specific solution. However if you decide to reinvent then write a good documentation and make the backup optional – no admin likes it when a partition pops up from nowhere. Unpartitioned space [may be there for a reason](http://superuser.com/q/1173600/432690) and you shouldn't take it behind the admin's back. I wouldn't expect there will be space left at all.