# Store single file on multiple partitions

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-management

I want store a file movie named movie.mp4 to sda1 and sda2. Some of the parts are on sda1 and rest is on sda2. If I open the file will it work normally. How to do that

Comment: You can use lvm. https://serverfault.com/questions/692724/how-can-i-create-one-large-partiton-over-two-drives-in-centos

Comment: If this is ad-hoc (one-time need, single file) then see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1167639/432690).